# Error in parallel processing using ga linking external software

Tags: matlab, optimization, parallel-processing, opensees

I want to run an optimization problem using ga and gamultiobj which is a link between OpenSees and Matlab; To have optimum run time, I want to use the optim option "UseParallel" in MATLAB. To avoid the replacement of folders on each other, a trick that I have done is to assign a very big number (1e9) as an index to the folders in the objective function loop...but unfortunately, still I got errors because I used "regexprep" several times in MATLAB to modify plenty of lines in my code in OpenSees and save them in a new (.tcl) file with a new ID. So when I use clustered workers for parallel processing, I get errors which for example no file with x name exists or something like that...Maybe I should write a code that updates the ID of the OpenSees files that I sourced in my code or produce new OpenSees files each iteration and delete them at the end of the loop to save free space.
Can anyone help me with this issue??
I'm in a hurry for that!
Thanks in advance,
Sahar Ebrahimi

I tried to use the "UseParallel" option for an optimization problem but got several errors. I should mention that when I use a few workers, there is no error...as I increase the number of workers, these errors appear.

Comment: It seems that you need to identify workers when using parallel computing in optimization routines. Use the worker Ids, instead of random numbers, to create different folders. If it is the case please edit your question and remove unnecessary information. There is no need to copy/paste 400 lines of code here. Just explain the problem and provide a minimal example.

Comment: @rahnema1, I think I didn't explain the problem well. I caused you to have a misunderstanding. The trick I have done works well; In each iteration, folders with specific IDs are produced. The main issue is the files that should be surced from external software for estimating objective functions; Consider that, inside the cost function loop, I wrote a code that deletes a file after making changes. In serial processing, there is no error but when several workers work together because that file was deleted by one of the workers before, it gives an error of non-existence.

Comment: As you know the source of the problem, you need to create separate folders for each parallel worker and place the output of the external software to those folders and each worker should read/write to its own folder. Instead of relative path use absolute path for reading/writing to the file. For example instead of `fid3 = fopen('general/rayleighM.tcl', 'w');` use `fid3 = fopen('C:\data\general/rayleighM.tcl', 'w');`. If you use absolute path you don't need to use `cd` to change the current folder.

Comment: Instead of using random numbers as id use the worker id. [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/568620-is-it-possible-to-identify-workers-when-using-parallel-computing-in-optimization-routines) is explained how to find the worker id.

Comment: @rahnema1 I really appreciate your help. I will edit my code in light of your explanations. Hopefully, this will fix the issue.